# What happened to SafeConvertAll in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I am looking at the ServiceStack.UseCases application, specifically the ImageResizer project.  The code in Global.asax references an extension method called SafeConvertAll, which does not appear to be a part of SS any longer.  What happened to this function and what should I use to replace it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a safe wrapper around `ConvertAll` to treat `null` collections as empty collections, it's been replaced with a much shorter `Map()` alias, e.g:

```
public object Get(Images request)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(UploadsDir)
        .Map(x => x.SplitOnLast(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last());
}
```

You can also use `.Safe()` to return an empty collection for `null` collections letting you safely use LINQ extension methods like `.Select()`, e.g:

```
public object Get(Images request)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(UploadsDir)
      .Safe().Select(x => x.SplitOnLast(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last());
}
```

ImageResizer has just been upgraded to **v4.0.40** in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/commit/c14acab7f0628746b49625a6f32408b703ac2c52).